# How to get css value of an element inside array?

Tags: jquery, css, arrays

I have a list, and want to get the value of background of the last element.

```
    <ul>
        <li style="background: red;"></li>
        <li style="background: blue;"></li>
        <li style="background: yellow;"></li>
        <li style="background: white;"></li>
    </ul>
```

and I use this jQuery script

```
var color = $( 'ul li' ).get(-1).css('background');
```

but it's not working. I googled it, but nothing found.
Could any one help me to find out the problem.

EDITED: this is not working on IE, my be I am wrong. but isn't any other way?

```
$( 'ul li:last' ).css('background');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All answers above will propably output empty string.

Please check:

```
var color = $('ul li').eq(-1).css('background-color');
```

In fact, you are seting the background-color, no background itself.

JsFiddle to prove: http://jsfiddle.net/7gxkp/

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
 var color = $( 'ul li:last' ).css('background');
```

Reason is `get(-1)` returns DOM element which doesn't have css method, css is a method of jquery object and not Native DOM element.

or do :

```
var color = $( 'ul li' ).get(-1).style.background;
```

You can also use jquery `.last()`

```
 var color = $( 'ul li' ).last().css('background');
```

*Note that jquery css uses `getComputerStyle` so you may end up getting all the background properties of the element (defaulted by the user agent as well) not just the color. If you want just the color using jquery `css` then you may want to specify `.css('background-color')` explicitly.*

Comment: I do not want to use this piece of code, I don't know why but it is not working on IE

Comment: @aliA It should work on IE, if it doesn't work then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @undefined `:last` css selector won't work in IE8 and less i guess if so jquery covers for it right?

Comment: Yes, jQuery 1.9 and below support IE and `:last` selector works in those browsers, however, as you know jQuery 2+ doesn't support IE8 and below.

Comment: @PSL jQuery doesn't depend on the browser's built-in selector support, it does it all by itself. This is one of the ways you get better cross-browser behavior when using jQuery.

Comment: @Barmar @:undefined Thanks, that's what i guessed. Anyways probably this is a different issue.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code doesn't work is because `get()` returns the DOM node, which doesn't have a `css()` function. You're looking for this:

```
$( 'ul li' ).eq(-1).css('background');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on the usage of get, but you can use CSS selectors with your jquery to do it like

```
var color = $( 'ul li:last-child' ).css('background');
```

It should be simpler! Let me know if this works for you! :)